# Loop inside Namespaces of an assembly?

Tags: c#, namespaces, assemblies

I have a method that was dooing some work on all the classes of an assembly :

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    [...]
}
```

The thing is that now, I'd like to split my code for each namespace of my assembly ! Something like

```
var library = Assembly.LoadFrom(libraryPath);
IEnumerable<Type> types = library.GetTypes();

foreach (/*namespace in my assembly*/)
{
    foreach (Type type /*in my Namespace*/)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

But after all my researches on the web and here on SO I didn't find anything that I like...
The only thing I was able to do is :

```
List<string> namespaceList = new List<string>();

foreach (Type type in types)
{
    if (!namespaceList.Contains(type.Namespace))
    {
        namespaceList.Add(type.Namespace);
    }
}
```

But I can't do anything with this List...
Yes, I can loop through all members on namespaceList and then loop on all types and test if they are (string comparaison) inside the current namespace, but I really feel like it's not the way to go...

Any help would be really appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [LINQ GroupBy method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx):

```
var namespaces = library.GetTypes().GroupBy(t => t.Namespace);
foreach (var typesInNamespace in namespaces)
{
    foreach (var type in typesInNamespace)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hooo, sounds like exactly what I was looking for !